# Trouble aligning text with image in container

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a small image before some text in a container. The image is a little higher up than the text, I am having trouble aligning the text with the image. The image is centered vertically, but the text is a little lower. Any help would be great!

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class ="additional-container" data-equal="div">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="additional" style="background-image:url('<?=$url?>');">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/rollup.png" />
    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 350px rgba(86, 159, 223, .9);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional span {
  padding: 15px;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional img {
  padding-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: What about defining a line-height to the span element, equals to the image height? Perhaps also turning padding-top and padding-bottom to auto. Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional span,
.pagecontent .cols .col.one .additional img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @MrDevRI You are welcome and don't forget to [remove the extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`